# What's the risk of using no remote signer if the key is encrypted?

Tags: baking

New to baking, I want to clarify what are the risks associated with generating an encrypted key and running the baker on a single cloud machine. I understand what the remote-signer is for.

I'm just curious how possibly the attacker can steal the tokens if the baker stores an encrypted key (cannot do anything without a passphrase to unlock key)?

Answer (score 1):

The risk is that the encryption passphrase could be brute-forced if an attacker gains a copy of your encrypted private key.